# How to solve the problem of boost shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ip::tcp::socket> socket_ptr;
boost::asio::io_service service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::tcp::v4(), 2001);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acc(service, ep);
socket_ptr sock_ptr(new ip::tcp::socket(service));

void handle_accept(socket_ptr sock, const boost::system::error_code &err);
void start_accept(socket_ptr sock);

void handle_accept(socket_ptr sock_ptr_, const boost::system::error_code &err) 
{
    if (err) return;
    socket_ptr sock_ptr_(new ip::tcp::socket(service));
    start_accept(sock_ptr_);
}

void start_accept(socket_ptr sock_ptr_) 
{
    acc.async_accept(*sock_ptr_, boost::bind(handle_accept, sock_ptr_, _1) );
}


int main()
{
    start_accept(sock_ptr);
    service.run();
}
```

The compiled code reported an error, but it was unclear where the error was. I would like to ask you to help solve this difficult problem

```
/mnt/hgfs/share/home/Cpp/tcp/io_service/task_3/service/server.cpp: In function ‘void handle_accept(socket_ptr, const boost::system::error_code&)’:
/mnt/hgfs/share/home/Cpp/tcp/io_service/task_3/service/server.cpp:21:25: error: declaration of ‘socket_ptr sock_ptr_’ shadows a parameter
     socket_ptr sock_ptr_(new ip::tcp::socket(service));
                         ^

    "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -fPIC -std=c++11    -c -o "bin/gcc-4.8/debug/server.o" "/mnt/hgfs/share/home/Cpp/tcp/io_service/task_3/service/server.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin/gcc-4.8/debug/server.o...
...skipped <p/mnt/hgfs/share/home/Cpp/tcp/io_service/task_3/stage>service for lack of <pbin/gcc-4.8/debug>server.o...
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 1 target...
```

Comment: It's exactly what the error message says: `handle_accept` takes a parameter named `sock_ptr_`, and also declares a local variable named `sock_ptr_`. Once the local variable is declared, it's no longer possible to access the parameter. As a first step, give the variable a different name, to avoid confusion if nothing else. However, it's suspicious that `handle_accept` takes a parameter that it has no intention of using. Did you actually mean to create a new socket, and not use the one passed as parameter?

Comment: Thank you very much. I seem to understand what I was wrong in an instant.

Comment: The book describes that "after using this socket, you create a new socket, and then call start_accept () again to create another asynchronous operation of' waiting for the client to connect', so that the service.run () loop remains busy all the time". Should I handle the passed-in parameter sockt

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with the library you are using. If you are indeed supposed to manipulate two distinct `socket_ptr` instances, give them different names.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because an argument and a local variable of the function `handle_accept` is sharing `sock_ptr_`. Give one (or both) of them another different name(s).